# Assembly - Moving Floating Point Number

Tags: assembly, floating-point

I am new in Assembly, I did a lot of searches before asking this but I quite could not understand/find anything I am looking for.

```
fstp dword ptr [eax+00000124]
```

I have this line, so how do I edit it to store any floating number on [eax+00000124],

e.g. storing number 6 on that address.

mov instruction won't work good for this nor I couldn't understand/find needed fpu instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store 6.0 with `fstp`, you first need 6.0 in a floating point register. The easiest way to get it there is to load it from memory.. I think that sort of misses the point in this case.

Anyway you can use a normal integer `mov` to store it, just convert 6.0 to its bit pattern and store that,

```
mov dword ptr [eax+124], 0x40c00000
```

Comment: @FiatPax Note that this would replace a 3 byte long instruction with a 10 byte long instruction. If you make this change in OllyDbg this will result in one or more instructions following the `ftsp` instruction being overwritten.

Comment: @RossRidge 7 by my count, because the offset is small, C7 40 7C 00 00 C0 40 (gives the same problem of course)

Comment: I think `00000124` is a hexadecimal number. But yah, I counted wrong, in that case it would replace a 6 byte instruction with a 10 byte one.